# Should I used process.exit(1) when an error occurs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I have a simple Node.js program that attempts to read a file that does not exists and therefore an error will occur. My question is should I use `process.exit(1)` in this scenario or not? When I comment out the `process.exit(1)` and echo $? I get a value of 0 which means the process executed successfully.

index.js

```
'use strict';
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
try {
    const contents = readFileSync('noFile.txt');
    console.log(contents);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use it.
According to Node.js docs-
In most situations, it is not actually necessary to call process.exit() explicitly. The Node.js process will exit on its own if there is no additional work pending in the event loop. The process.exitCode property can be set to tell the process which exit code to use when the process exits gracefully.
Calling process.exit() will force the process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending that have not yet completed fully, including I/O operations to process.stdout and process.stderr.
[To know more, you can read docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code)

Comment: When the error occurs will the pending asynchronous operations terminate anyways, yes or no?

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for - If it is necessary to terminate the Node.js process due to an error condition, throwing an uncaught error and allowing the process to terminate accordingly is safer than calling process.exit(). Thank you for the help.